# Access to this from iframe event listener

Tags: javascript, html, events, iframe, lit-element

I work in a project using shadowDom. My goal is to print the content from another page using a hidden iframe.

From my the print page (loaded as an **iframe** inside the main one), I do the following:

```
window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('printEvent'));
```

Inside the **calling page**, I have the following code, inside the template :

```
  <iframe
        name="print-iframe"
        src=${url}
        style="display:none;"
      ></iframe>
```

Then inside the Javascript of the calling page.

```
// Event listening
window.document.addEventListener('printEvent', this._printIframe);

// Event handler
private _printIframe(): void {
  window.frames['print-iframe'].print();
}
```

The event is received but then I get this error.

```
app.development.js:45411 ERROR message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'print' of undefined.
```

Why can't I get the iframe from the event handler ?
I tried adding an id and target the iframe with `this.shadowDom.getElementById('iframe-id')` but it returns undefined because `this` is not bound to the context of my calling class, so `this.shadowDom` returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `LitElement` it uses the native `this.shadowRoot` rather than whatever polyfill generates `this.shadowDom`.

However, while you can add `firstUpdated` and find/subscribe your events there it's easier to add them to the template directly:

```
return html`
  <iframe
    src=${url}
    @printEvent=${this._printIframe}
    style="display:none;"></iframe>
`;
...

private _printIframe(e): void {
  const iframe = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe');
  iframe.print();
}
```

You can simplify this further with a `query` decorator:

```
@query('iframe') private iframe: HTMLFrameElement;

private _printIframe(e) {
  this.iframe.print();
}
```